# How to apply a function to a multi keyed pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, key

I'm performing a multidimensional lookup to assign a value in a new column.

I have a table that has some historical employee data by month. There are **two unique people** in this example, and they can have multiple jobs within a month.

I want to create a new column that tells me if each unique person has an eligible job based on the conditions below. The challenge is each row has to be considered by month/year.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Month': ["January", "January", "January", "February", "February", "February", "March", "March", "March", "March"],
        'Year': [2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016],
        'Job #': [1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,3],
        'Pay Group': ["Excluded","Included","Excluded","Excluded","Included","Included","Excluded","Exclcuded","Excluded","Included"],
        'Name': ["John","Bill","Bill","John","John","Bill","John","Bill","Bill","Bill"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Month', 'Year', 'Job #', 'Pay Group', 'Name'])

df
```

Eligible Jobs Conditions:

- If ( `Job #` = 1 AND `Pay Group` = Include ) AND if the prior condition is false, then look for the next largest `Job #` within the given `month/year` AND `Pay Group` = Includes

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

You want to for each person, within each month/year, you want to grab the smallest job # such that `Pay Group == Included`.

Filter only those that are included.  Sort by Job #. Group by year, month, and name taking the index of the minimum obseravation.  Use this to assign a new column.

```
dfi = df[df['Pay Group'] == 'Included'].sort_values('Job #')
gc = ['Year', 'Month', 'Name'] 
idx = dfi.groupby(gc, as_index=False)['Job #'].idxmin()
df['Eligible Job'] = 'Not Eligible'
df.ix[idx] = 'Eligible'

df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks piRSquared. This filtered great. There is another part to this... I need this to create a new column that flags these as eligible jobs, e.g. 'Eligible Job' : "Eligible" / "Not Eligible".

Also, after this is done, how do I reset the groupby so I can get back to the full table?

Comment: almost there. It looks like the code overrode the original lines for "Eligible". I'm looking to preserve the original table, but only having the "Eligible Job" column = "Eligible" or "Not Eligible".

Comment: it looks like the code overrode the original lines for "Eligible". I'm looking to preserve the original table, but only having the "Eligible Job" column = "Eligible" or "Not Eligible".